# como solucionar que un slideJS se carge como "script de fuente no autorizada"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, slider

Tengo un slide que configure desde slideJS y en local funciona bien pero cuando lo subo se bloquea por el navegador por no reconocer la fuente, y al colocar que la cargue igual, obviamente me califica como pagina "no segura" en rojo.
Es el primer slide que realizo asi, esto se puede solucionar o tengo que hacerlo yo de cero?
la web es www.timondigital.com/web por si quieren ver el problema
gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas llamando el CDN de Jquery de esta manera "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" Prueba llamarlo "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"